# Does python have a "causes_exception()" function?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def causes_exception(lamb):
    try:
       lamb()
       return False
    except:
       return True
```

I was wondering if it came already in any built-in library?

/YGA

Edit: Thx for all the commentary.  It's actually impossible to detect whether code causes an exception without running it -- otherwise you could solve the halting problem (raise an exception if the program halts).  I just wanted a syntactically clean way to filter a set of identifiers for those where the code didn't except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of that function, or anything similar, in the Python standard library.

It's rather misleading - if I saw it used, I might think it told you *without calling the function* whether the function could raise an exception.

Comment: I agree.  Not that i've ever encountered such a method.

Answer (score 8):

No, as far as I know there is no such function in the standard library. How would it be useful? I mean, presumably you would use it like this:

```
if causes_exception(func):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

But instead, you could just do

```
try:
    func()
except SomeException:
    # do something else
else:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 4):

There's `assertRaises(exception, callable)` in `unittest` module and this is probably the only place where such check makes sense.

In regular code you can never be 100% sure that `causes_exception` you suggested are not causing any side effects.